# Django and Ajax security concern

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have this "model"

```
class messages(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        (u'read',u'read'),
        (u'unread',u'unread')
        )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=status_choices,default='unread')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="sender")
```

And this is my view which fetches user messages and passes it to javascript.

```
@login_required
def ajax_fetch_messages(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print(request.POST['user'])
        # first check that user himself asked for his/her messages
        requested_user = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.POST['user'])
        if requested_user == request.user:
            # do processing of messages
            user_messages = messages.objects.filter(user=requested_user,status='unread')
            '''try:
                response = dumps(messages)
            except:
                print("Unable to dump messages")'''
            return HttpResponse(user_messages)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("You're not authorised to do that")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("This method can't be called this way")
```

Now I have following concerns

1. I'm unable to jsonify the objects returned by the above mentioned view.So I have to send "message" objects returned by the view to javascript.
2. Is it safe to pass python objects to javascript without jsonfying the objects at django    end?If not,then what are the issues that can arise?

So,what do you have to say about my problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why can't you jsonify your object? in the case you send the object (which I doubt you can unless there is some middleware handling the conversion) it will pickle it and sent it as a string, so you can always jsonify any object no matter what.

for example, if I want to sent all the info from an object named "Company":

```
comp = Company.objects.all()[0]
info = {"name": comp.name, "url": comp.url, "created_on": datetime.strftime(comp.created_on, "%d-%m-%Y")}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(info))
```

take into account that everything you are sending should be a string (or integer which will be automatically converted to string).

After you sent the json in your javascript you just need to get the object and parse it:

`obj = JSON.parse(response)`

And that's it! Now about the security problem the only issue that comes to my mind is that you are sending information that you will probably not use like the object id, besides that there is no real security risk.

Now if what you want is to sent a rendered view so you can use the power of templates you could do this:

```
from django.template import Context, loader

context = Context({'user': UserObject, 'company': CompanyObject})
html_t = loader.get_template(HTML_TEMPLATE_PATH)
html = html_t.render(context)

return HttpResponse(html)
```

now in your ajax you will receive the rendered template which you can use right away without any need for json.

Comment: It says:

TypeError: <User: rayne> is not JSON serializable

Comment: you have to make the user a string also, just do a nested dictionary, like this: `info = {'user': {'name': 'rayne', 'last_name': ....}}

Comment: Okay,then I have to resort to the same technique which I used to populate my pages with more posts using ajax.What I did there was I converted post objects to a dictionary containing only strings and then I returned the jsonified dict to javascript.
But here I wanted to harness the power of templates by using {{ message.status }} etc.So,I guess I can't do that.